# Instantiate and destroy GameObject/ParticleSystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a script that should Instantiate a particle system and destroy it after a certain amount of time, but after the object is Instantiated, this error code shows up:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'ParticleSystem' has been 
>       destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>       Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the 
>       object.

the script is currently goes as such:

```
public class MuzzleFlash : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform gun;
    public ParticleSystem smoke;
    public ParticleSystem flare;
    public ParticleSystem bullet;
    private float smokeTime = 0.2f;

    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            smokeFun();
            flare.Play();
            bullet.Play();
        }
    }

    void smokeFun()
    {
        Instantiate(smoke, gun);
        Destroy(smoke, smokeTime);
    }
}
```

How can i Instantiate this particle system and destroy it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are attempting to destroy the prefab `ParticleSystem` which the `smoke` variable not the `ParticleSystem`  you instantiated.

The `Instantiate` function returns any GameObject it instantiates. To destroy the `ParticleSystem` you just instantiated, you have to instantiate it, store it in a temporary variable then destroy it with that temporary variable later on.

```
void smokeFun()
{
    //Instantiate and store in a temporary variable
    ParticleSystem smokeInstance = Instantiate(smoke, gun);
    //Destroy the Instantiated ParticleSystem 
    Destroy(smokeInstance, smokeTime);
}
```